# PHP eval syntax

Tags: php, mysql, eval

I need help figuring out the syntax for the eval function - or even if eval is the right approach.  I have a column in my mysql database which holds the name of a PHP function I need to run.  There are also PHP variables that would like to leave as variable until they are passed to the function.  Below is what I have so far:

```
eval($valRec[$key]($key,$value));
```

$valRec is the array which contains the results of a mysql SELECT. $key is a variable which references the name of the column that contains the function name.

$key and $value are the PHP variables that I need to pass into the function.

In the end, I want to end up with:

```
functionName($key,$value);
```

which PHP should run.

Hopefully I explained it clearly - thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: can you var_dump($valRec); ??

Comment: never never use eval. There are a fewwwww corner cases where it may be necessary, but I can pretty much guarentee you will never run into them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is:

```
$valRec[$key]($key,$value);
```

Reference: [variable functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php).

Comment: Could it really be that simple?!?  I have a couple tests that I'm going to be running in the next few minutes - will let you know if that works!

Comment: `$foo = 'bar'; $foo();` Calls function `bar`. That's all that is happening here, except that the string is contained in an array. Rarely is `eval()` ever needed in PHP.

Comment: I have a few bugs to work out, but this worked. I guess I was just overcomplicating it!  Thanks!

Comment: (Just be aware that "variable functions" are like "variable variables" and do not represent first-class functions; the variable must still resolve to the *name* of a function.)

Answer (score 4):

Eval is probably not what you want. Look at `call_user_func` and `call_user_func_array`. They let you call a function whose name is in a variable.

```
call_user_func($valRec[$key], $key, $value);
```

Comment: I didn't end up using eval as Matthew's solution worked - but I will definitely keep call_user_func in mind in case I ever run into a situation where I need something like this again!

Answer (score 2):

In php, you could do below;

```
$func = 'strtolower';
$foo = $func($bar);
```

So in your case, `$valRec[$key]($key,$value);` will just work.

***[Check the demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/1U9uDA)***

***Addtion:***
The reason why your `eval` not work is because `eval` need to take a string as parameter, not don't forget `;` to end the statement, or it will be syntax error. 
So you need to do:

```
eval($valRec[$key].'($key, $value);');
```

Comment: Thanks xdazz.  Per Matthew's solution above I figured out that I was just overcomplicating this!

Comment: @pst Yes, `eval` should not be used, i just mean to point out why `eval` in the op's code not work.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used PHP recently, but the concept of `eval` is to evaluate a string.

As such, you need to create the string representing the line of code you want run.

In your case that means:

```
eval($valRec[$key] . '($key, $value);');
```

You've said it yourself, you want to end up with `functionName($key,$value);` so you need to make a string that is that, then pass it to `eval`.

Comment: The solution provided by @Matthew above worked - but I really appreciate your help as well!!

Answer (score 0):

see this example,

```
<?php
    $string = 'cup';
    $name = 'coffee';
    $str = 'This is a $string with my $name in it.';
    echo $str. "\n";
    eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
    echo $str. "\n";
?>
```

this is the output

```
This is a $string with my $name in it.
This is a cup with my coffee in it.
```

you need to read this, **[when is eval evil in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/951868/491243)**

Comment: John - thanks for the example.  This is very similar to the example in the PHP manual - which I read over and tried to apply unsuccessfully.

Comment: @Alan have a look at [this](http://changelog.ca/log/2005/06/14/the-proper-way-to-use-php-eval)

Comment: Thanks for the link!  Per the solution provided by Matthew I didn't end up using eval - but I will make sure to remember this if I end up using it in the future!